# htaccess redirect a specific page with cookie value if exists otherwise redirect another page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, cookies

I'm using the below redirection code in php but this should be done in htaccess. Please help me.

```
//when user open this link
$canonical="/category/story/horror/?search=ghost&page=2"; 
if(empty($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
  //asking user to select the language. then store it in cookie. 
} else
{
  //redirect him to language page
  $canonical="/category/story/horror/en/?search=ghost&page=2";
}
```

These are dynamic pages. So I can't add language to the menu directly. The user will click on the type or category on the homepage. On the type or category page **("/category/story/love")** it will open in the default language (I get it via the location API) but a pop-up will open immediately to confirm the user's language. If a user clicks on a language there, it will be redirected to another page for that language.**("/category/story/love/en/" or "/category/story/love/fr/")**. This link will be available for all searches and filters from now on. But the only thing is, the first link does not have any language name, because it can be opened from the main menu or social media.

```
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Z0-9_-]+)/([A-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ message/?type=$1&category=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^message/([A-Z]{2})/?$ message/?lang=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^type/([A-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ message/?type=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Z0-9_-]+)/([A-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ message/?type=$1&category=$2 [NC,QSA,L] [NC,QSA,L]
```

These are previous redirections. See the last two. Now I need to find out if there is a cookie labeled "lang" and use this cookie name in the last two URLs above. Something like below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !lang=$name [NC]
RewriteRule ^type/([A-Z0-9_-]+)/{$name}/?$ message/?type=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Z0-9_-]+)/([A-Z0-9_-]+)/{$name}/?$ message/?type=$1&category=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Please guide me with right syntax.

Comment: I don't think I follow... why not simply pass the language code (if any) as a parameter to your script if it appears in the URL? Which would then override the cookie? `message/?type=$1` - this is not strictly a valid endpoint as it requires additional rewrites/subrequests. `^message/([A-Z]{2}+)/?$` - the `+` is superfluous here (it is arguably an error).

Comment: "but this should be done in htaccess." - why?

Comment: At first we don't know the user's preferred language to read our website stories, poems, jokes, etc. So I show a popup when a user enters the page for the first time. Then I get the language code and save it in the cookie. After that, I can easily use that code to show the pages, filters and all. So I need it only at the first time.

On the home screen, there are many links to each category of story and poem. So I thought it would be nice to redirect the page using htaccess to the language version if the cookie is set for the first time.

Comment: Yes I want to use htaccess. I need the correct syntax

Comment: By the sounds of it you want to actually change the URL of your internal links in the generated HTML, based on the value of the cookie? However, this isn't something you should do in `.htaccess`. (?)

Comment: No bro. Actually, the generated URL is to be redirected to the cookie value when the page loads.

Example:

If a user visit our website first time, he click on story button in home page
example.com/type/story/

At first I get the cookie from user. These are all done already. 

Second time the user visits our website, his language preference is in cookie value. So if he clicks the same link in the home page, 
example.com/type/story/ it should redirect to example.com/type/story/fr/ since the user already selected French (fr) in language preference.

Comment: So, I need the redirection only after getting the cookie value from user.There are 120 categories in story and poetry. So I can't attach the language variable with all the links. So I prefer redirection when the user click the links.